# keep android screen from dimming while activity is running

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

For my android app, I want to keep the screen from dimming while certain activities (e.g. CatActivity) are in the resume state. Does anyone know how to do that? is there a way to declare so in the manifest or in the activity itself?

**UPDATE**

I found the answer:

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Is there a way to turn it off? I don't see a `removeFlags` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the flag simply call the `clearFlags()` method:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```